# How to use Borland C++ in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, borland-c++

I have a Borland C++ command-line compiler. Is there any way to enable its toolchain in VS code to use Lint, Find Errors, Intellisense, etc?
Is it possible to get it done without having a VS Code Extension for it?

PS: I KNOW that Borland C++ is a stone-age deprecated compiler. Anyways, I need to get a school project done and it would be very convenient if I could get it done using VS Code.

EDIT: I may have caused some confusion and apologize for it. The compiler I have is the Borland 5.5 command-line compiler tool circa ~1999 (and not the latest v10.1 C++11 enabled compiler).

Comment: show code You want used. Some code is portable, some is portable with additiona work, some totally not portable. In general: borland/embecadero generated C++ classes are mostly portable to Delphi, not to standard C++

Comment: @JacekCz I'm doing a lot newbie of programs ranging from "HELLO WORLD" to loops, simple programs showing classes/structs and such. The most complex code is that of Linked-List.

Comment: Only standard C++ coding is portable between compilers. Borland/Embarcadero uses a lot of vendor-specific extensions to provide compatibility with Delphi-based libraries. If you write portable C++ code, there is no need to use Borland/Embarcadero compilers in Visual Studio, just compile the code as-is using Microsoft's compiler instead.  And FYI, only the old Borland C++ compiler is stone-age. [Embarcadero's C++ compiler is revamped](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/ccompiler) to bring it into modern C++11 compliance and support multi-platform development.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Buddy, I AM talking about the depriciated Borland c++ compiler. The Embarcadero compiler you're mentioning is version 10.1(Latest, I believe) but I am talking about the 5.5 version. "The one in which namespace is not compatible" is how i used to refer it. I referred it as Embarcadero/Borland since when i downloaded it (a few years ago), it was available at Embarcadero's site . I knew if it was Embacadero's Latest compiler, I wouldn't be having any issue. But no, my school just HAS TO use that stone-age discarded stuff.

Comment: Are you actually required to use that compiler for the school project? I can think of at least a few other compilers that would be much MUCH better if all you are doing is simple stuff like classes and linked lists.

Comment: Also, there is no way anyone would have wasted their time making a VS Code extension for that compiler, because everyone is using more modern compilers.

Comment: That is no longer a school I would have to attend.  Your professor needs to be reminded that Y2K didn't blow up the world.

Comment: Funny thing. I just encountered yet another professor who thinks that Borland C++ Builder 6 is the best way to teach students some C++. I suppose we'll need to wait full 40 years (like jews in the desert, and for similar reasons) to really get rid of that thing.

Answer (score 1):

bcc32 still does not have any extension to integrate easily with VSCode unlike gcc or CL,
However, you can still configure it to use from the command line, 
bcc32 is fairly simple compiler to use from command line, so just write your code on VSCode, and then you have 2 choices, Either you use the VSCode terminal to run the compiler (for ex. > bcc32 main.cpp)
Or you can edit the VSCode tasks file.

Here is a simple tasks.json file that should at least compile a main.cpp program (You can automate the build for a project through a make file, or even a batch file, and replace "bcc32 main.cpp" with this batch file.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build bcc32",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "bcc32 main.cpp"
        },
        {
            "label": "Run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "main.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```